# Wordpress compare post date

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to check if a Wordpress post was posted after a specified date. For example if a post was posted after (2014-04-24) it will have a featured image, if it was poster before it wont have a featured image. If anyone could help that would be great.

```
            global $post;
            $compare_date = strtotime( "2014-04-24" );
            $post_date    = strtotime( $post->post_date );
            print_r($post_date);
            if ($compare_date > $post_date ){
                //show featured image 
                the_post_thumbnail('home-thumbnail'); 
            } else {

                // Dont show featured image
            }
```

Comment: what is problem here?

Comment: If I read the requirement correctly, don't you want your comparison the other way round: `if ($post_date > $compare_date)`?  That should be true if the post date is after 2014-04-24